# I have a default package that I can't delete on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I'm not exactly sure how I did this, but I can't remove it.

See below screenshot, I now have a (default package) that is causing me errors.

[image: Screenshot of (default package)]

I've gone to the file location and it doesn't exist, if I right click to delete, the delete option is greyed out. I've tried closing and reopening the project as well as refreshing the project and neither work.

[image: File location of SRC folder]

Can anyone give me any advice on how to remove this package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that's it's because I changed my JRE to 1.8. Upon moving back to JavaSE-16, I have fixed it/the package disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Move your java file from the default package to any other package and then refresh the project issue will be resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your input, unfortunately the package was already empty and I had already tried refreshing. As I mentioned, my issue and in turn fix was that I had changed the JRE.